# mySQL JOIN add text to variable

Tags: mysql, variables, join

Here is a mySQL query. The trouble is that we need to add a prefix and suffix to theme.ref in order to make it match

```
SELECT * FROM content LEFT JOIN theme ON content.ID LIKE theme.ref 
WHERE content.status = 1 AND content.parent = 11 AND content.type = 'team' 
ORDER BY content.position ASC
```

On the first link where it says `content.ID LIKE theme.ref` is it possible to add the text 'ID' before theme.ref and ',' after it. Can this be done and if so how.

eg. `'ID'.theme.reg.','`  obviously that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`content.ID LIKE concat('ID',theme.ref,',')`
(which is equivalent of `content.ID = concat('ID',theme.ref,',')` if theme.ref does not contain wildcard characters)

But the query will be inefficient. Probably, it should be rewritten or the whole data model changed.

Comment: I will rewrite the structure so as not to require this. I take it it is slow because of the concat and not because of the JOIN?

Comment: Shortly, it can be inefficient because of concat usage in join predicate :) Having such join predicate greatly restricts MySQL engine in ways it can choose optimal query plan.

Comment: Join on a.x=b.x (so called natural join) is good with any of available algorithms: nested loops from a to b (using index on b.x), nested loops from b to a (using index on a.x), hash join and sort-merge join - so RDBMS can choose any and build optimal plan. Join on a.x=F(b.x) is more restricted - it can be done only with nested loops from b to a (using index on a.x), just because you can not have index on F(b.x). Hash join and sort-merge join are difficult to implement is such case, so most RDBMS fail to apply them.

Comment: Join on F(a.x,b.x)=0 is a nightmare, because it can be done only filtering full cortesian product (a x b) with the predicate.